# Python packaging issue: No module named steamcloud

Tags: python, python-2.7

Attached is a zip file containing the files I'm having trouble with: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2btesdznqevjhz7/airship-pypa.zip?dl=0

Basically I have three subdirectories: `airship`, `airship.icloud`, and `airship.steamcloud`. Each has a `setup.py` file and an `airship` subdirectory, and the appropriate subdirectory within containing the right file, for example `airship.icloud/airship/icloud/airship.icloud.py`. I ran `sudo pip install -U .` in all three of these directories, and `pip list` shows all three packages installed. However, when I try to run `airship` (entry point to `airship/airship/__init__.py`), it fails to import the `steamcloud` package:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airship", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('airship==1.1', 'console_scripts', 'airship')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/airship/__init__.py", line 4, in main
    airship.sync()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/airship/airship.py", line 21, in sync
    module = importlib.import_module('.' + modulename, 'airship')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named steamcloud
```

The relevant code:

```
modules = {'steamcloud': None, 'icloud': None}
modulenum = 0

for modulename in modules:
    # try:
        module = importlib.import_module('.' + modulename, 'airship')
        if module.init():
            print(modulename + ' was imported')
            modules[modulename] = module
            modulenum += 1
    # except:
        # pass
```

The `try` statement is meant for the possibility that the user does not have the relevant package installed, but has been commented out for debugging, as has the print statement been added.

I can confirm that `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/airship/steamcloud/airship.steamcloud.py` exists and has the correct code.

The iCloud module is loading fine, so why isn't the Steam Cloud module?

Offshoot question: Is there a better way to check if a package is installed without doing a `try`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put dots in the names of your Python files and directory.  It gets confusing.

Python is not looking for a file named `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/airship/steamcloud/airship.steamcloud.py`.  It is looking for a file named `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/airship/steamcloud.py`, if I'm understanding your code and error correctly.